# Unable to see created database in hive in specified location

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I'm new to Hive.

I've created a database in Hive and by default the database is created in Hive warehouse. When I run the -ls against Hive Warehouse I'm able to see created database practice.db.

Query Used to Create Database:

> create database practice
>
> COMMENT 'Holds all practice tables';

I've created another database in Hive. When I run the -ls command against the path where I created the database unable to see practice_first.db.

Query Used to Create Database:

> create database practice_first
>
> COMMENT 'Holds all practice tables'
>
> LOCATION '/somepath in hdfs here';

Even I checked in Hive warehouse practice_first.db is not there in hive warehouse also.

When I run show database I'm able to see practice_first database in list of databases.

Any suggestion where Hive created the practice_first.db.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Just tested to make sure it should appear without any tables being added and it does.  Try using describe on the database after you create to verify the path:

```
hive> create database test1 COMMENT 'testing' LOCATION '/user/testuser/test1.db';
OK
Time taken: 0.63 seconds
hive> describe database test1;
OK
test1  testing hdfs://nameserviceHA/user/testuser/test1.db        testuser    USER
Time taken: 0.183 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> exit;
$ hadoop fs -ls /user/testuser/ | grep test
drwxr-xr-x   - testuser testgrp          0 2015-02-12 15:43 /user/testuser/test1.db
```

Doing the same with the default location will automatically name the dir with a .db extension.  Also it looks like the group in this case will be hive instead of the user's group:

```
hive> drop database test1;
OK
Time taken: 0.379 seconds
hive> create database test1 COMMENT 'testing';                                 OK
Time taken: 0.319 seconds
hive> describe database test1;
OK
test1  testing hdfs://nameserviceHA/user/hive/warehouse/test1.db      testuser    USER
Time taken: 0.263 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> exit;

$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse | grep test1
drwxrwxrwt   - testuser         hive                0 2015-02-12 15:53 /user/hive/warehouse/test1.db
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be created at the path specified by `LOCATION`

Check [HIVE-1537](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1537) and [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL)

Comment: Hi @sonic As per the JIRA Link it should be in the specified location. But when I run -ls against specified location the practice_first.db is not there in the specified location. Any suggestion please.

Comment: well it should be, i just tried it out in my machine and it was there.

Comment: one more point, when you are specifying the location, there won't be a .db extension to the folder unless and until you specify so.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to see **practice_first.db** directory if

1) you create the database in default location.

2) you explicitly provide the name of the directory as **practice_first.db** in LOCATION in CREATE DATABASE statement.